# Adding column to empty DataFrames via a loop

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have the following code:

```
for key in temp_dict:
temp_dict[key][0][0] = temp_dict[key][0][0].insert(0, "Date", None)
```

where temp_dict is:

```
    {'0.5SingFuel': [[Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Month, Trades, -0.25, -0.2, -0.15, -0.1, -0.05, 0.0, 0.05, 0.1, 0.15, 0.2, 0.25, Total]
Index: []]], 'Sing180': [[Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Month, Trades, -0.25, -0.2, -0.15, -0.1, -0.05, 0.0, 0.05, 0.1, 0.15, 0.2, 0.25, Total]
Index: []]], 'Sing380': [[Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Month, Trades, -0.25, -0.2, -0.15, -0.1, -0.05, 0.0, 0.05, 0.1, 0.15, 0.2, 0.25, Total]
Index: []]]}
```

What I would like to have is:

```
{'0.5SingFuel': [[Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Date, Month, Trades, -0.25, -0.2, -0.15, -0.1, -0.05, 0.0, 0.05, 0.1, 0.15, 0.2, 0.25, Total]
Index: []]], 'Sing180': [[Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Date, Month, Trades, -0.25, -0.2, -0.15, -0.1, -0.05, 0.0, 0.05, 0.1, 0.15, 0.2, 0.25, Total]
Index: []]], 'Sing380': [[Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Date, Month, Trades, -0.25, -0.2, -0.15, -0.1, -0.05, 0.0, 0.05, 0.1, 0.15, 0.2, 0.25, Total]
Index: []]]}
```

My code produces the following error:

```
ValueError: cannot insert Date, already exists
```

I would have thought that I was looping from one dict key to the next, but I was going through the debugger and it looks like:

- Code does what it is supposed to
- Moves onto next key and the previous key becomes empty
- The new key already has "Date" in the columns and then the code tries to add it, which of course it can't

This probably makes no sense, hence why I need some help - I am confused.

I think I am mis-assigning the variables, but not completely sure how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem is that `insert` is kind of an inplace operation, so you don't need to reassign. The second problem is if the column exists, then `insert` does not work as you said, so you need to check if it is in the columns already, and maybe reorder to put this column as first.

```
# dummy dictionary, same structure
d = {0:[[pd.DataFrame(columns=['a','b'])]], 
     1:[[pd.DataFrame(columns=['a','c'])]]}

# name of the column to insert
col='c'

for key in d.keys():
    df_ = d[key][0][0] # easier to define a variable
    if col not in df_.columns:
        df_.insert(0,col,None)
    else: # reorder and reassign in this case, remove the else if you don't need
        d[key][0][0] = df_[[col] + df_.columns.difference([col]).tolist()]
print(d)
# {0: [[Empty DataFrame
# Columns: [c, a, b]                 # c added as column
# Index: []]], 1: [[Empty DataFrame
# Columns: [c, a]                    # c in first position now
# Index: []]]}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!